# Array of strings reading its input from file.txt C programming

Tags: c, arrays

I am having a problem and cant tell what is it.

```
struct arrayDB {
char *user[MAX_SIZE];
char *pass[MAX_SIZE];
char db[10][2];
};

void readFile(char fileName[100])
{
    char* word ;
    char line[90];
    FILE *passFile;
    int rowC=0;
    int chk=0;

    passFile=fopen(fileName,"rt");
    while(fgets(line,90,passFile)!=NULL)
    {
        word=strtok(line," ");
        rowC=rowC+1;
        while(word!=NULL)
        {
            printf("Count=%i \n",rowC);
            if(chk==0)
            {
                printf("word:%s\n",word);
                DB.user[rowC]=word;
                chk=1;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("word:%s\n",word);
                DB.pass[rowC]=word;

            }
            printf("r=%s , c=%s\n",DB.user[rowC],DB.pass[rowC]);
            word=strtok(NULL," ");

        }

        chk=0;
    }
    int i;

    for(i=1; i<6;i++)
    {
        printf("- %s , %s \n",DB.user[i],DB.pass[i]);
    }

 }
```

but the output I am getting that all the array elements is the same value which is the last word in the file 
as you can see in the pic

[image]

thanks

Comment: Is it really easier to put a screenshot instead of text copy/paste?

Comment: The code you are showing is not the code you ran the example with.  For one, in  the line `DB.pass[rowC]=word;` `DB` is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading every line into the same string `line`. Then when you use `strtok()`, it's returning pointers into this string, and you're storing these pointers into `DB`. So all the records in `DB` are pointing to locations in `line`, which gets overwritten each time you read another line from the file. When everything is done, `line` contains the contents of the last line of the file, and all the `DB` entries point to that.

Another problem is that `line` is a local variable, and pointers to it become invalid when the function returns.

To solve both problems, you need to make copies of the string and store these in `DB`. For example:

```
        DB.user[rowC]= strdup(word);
```

This also means that when you're done with a `DB` record, you need to call `free(DB.user[i])`

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

First, learn to use a debugger.  There are *[free ones](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)*, get one and turn it on to find all of these errors (that is what I did here)

Next,  for the code example you show to compile, the struct definition needs to support your code (currently, DB is not defined)

```
typedef struct  
{
    char *user[MAX_SIZE];
    char *pass[MAX_SIZE];
    char db[10][2];
}arrayDB;

arrayDB DB;//define DB
```

Next,

you need to allocate space for your string arrays:
something like:

```
for(i=0;i<MAX_SIZE;i++ )
{
    DB.user[i] = malloc(100);
    DB.pass[i] = malloc(100);
}
```

Next, don't forget to free them when done using them.

```
for(i=0;i<MAX_SIZE;i++ )
{
    free(DB.user[i]);
    free(DB.pass[i]);
}
```

Next, you cannot assign a string using an equal operator:

```
DB.pass[rowC]=word;
```

use strcpy (or some other string function) instead:

```
strcpy(DB.pass[rowC],word);
```

Next, this line:

```
printf("r=%s , c=%s\n",DB.user[rowC],DB.pass[rowC]);
```

Is called after a conditional statement where *either* `DB.user[rowC]` *or* `DB.pass[rowC]` will be written to, never both.  Suggest splitting this printf statement to print one or the other, and place it into the appropriate conditional branch.

Comment: thanks for all the tips. The thing is that I am java programmer. but i am trying to do socket programming in C and everything is different in C. Thank you again. I will try to do your recommendations

Comment: He *is* incrementing the index. Didn't you see the line `rowC = rowC + 1;`?

Comment: Yes.  Saw that after I put the last comment in.  I will edit that last comment out.  Thanks.